# How to use RCFProto in code blocks?

Tags: c++, rcf

I'm trying to use `RCFProto` to do some rpc work in ubuntu and I've successfully run the demo following the [tutorial](http://www.deltavsoft.com/RCFProto/distro/unix/cpp.html) ,but I don't know how to use it in my project in code blocks? Can anyone help me, what am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out myself,  I just need to set the linker libraries, include directories and follow the [instructions](http://www.deltavsoft.com/RCFProto/distro/unix/cpp.html) to install the Prerequisites. the everything is all set.